# System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes for file larger than 2GB

Tags: c#, file, memory, limit

I have a large file that I need to copy to memory for further processing. The software works fine for files smaller than 2GB, but as soon as they pass this limit I get an exception that ReadAllBytes only supports files smaller than 2GB.

```
byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file); // exception if file > 2GB
```

**What is the fastest way to copy a file larger than 2GB to memory?**

The process is already 64bit and the flag *gcAllowVeryLargeObjects* is already set.

Comment: You can increase the maximum: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054.aspx But the question is: why do you need to load all into memory at once? Use a stream based approach.

Comment: Read it in chunks and process it? Or make your process 64 bit?

Comment: @Tim and Soner, I guess that alone is not enough if process is 32 bit.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: you're right, it's mentioned in the first sentence. But i wouldn't load all into memory anyway.

Comment: What do you want to do with this file ? I'm quite sure you could achieve this with a stream like solution. Or Read Line By Line, If you provider more informations we could help find you a solution which is based on streams also it would be much more performant

Comment: It is worth to try and find another way that doesn't need this. This method will eventually cause you a lot of pain.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you can do anything faster than a memory mapped file http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx.

```
using ( var file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile( "F:\\VeryLargeFile.data" ) )
{
}
```

You can then use CreateViewAccessor or CreateViewStream to manipulate the data.