# joining mp3 in file larger that 2gb

Tags: c#

This method works but when the resulting file is > 2gb there is an error:

```
    >System.IO.IOException: The file is too long. This operation is currently limited to supporting files less than 2 gigabytes in size.

        public static void CombineMp3InDirectory(string dir, string resultFilenameFullPath)
        {
            var mp3sList = new List<string>();
            var d        = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
            var infos    = d.GetFiles();

            foreach (FileInfo f in infos) { mp3sList.Add(f.FullName); }

            using (var w = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(resultFilenameFullPath)))
            {
                mp3sList.ForEach(f => w.Write(File.ReadAllBytes(f)));
            }
        }

    **UPDATE**
    Works now after changing setting  gcAllowVeryLargeObjects in App.xaml:
(thanks to FrankerZ's hint )

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <runtime>
        <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
      </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Try to not read the hole file at once, read and write it in smaller blocks.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882004/system-io-file-readallbytes-for-file-larger-than-2gb