# How to read/write to a file which is over the size barrier of 2 GB?

Tags: c#, .net

So, i don't have a single idea to get through this situation i have a function that patches a file by replacing the values i want but he file i am trying to patch is about 4.5GB.
Here is the function :

```
private static readonly byte[] PatchFind = { 0x74, 0x72, 0x79 };
    private static readonly byte[] PatchReplace = { 0x79, 0x72, 0x74 };

    private static bool DetectPatch(byte[] sequence, int position)
    {
        if (position + PatchFind.Length > sequence.Length) return false;
        for (int p = 0; p < PatchFind.Length; p++)
        {
            if (PatchFind[p] != sequence[position + p]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void PatchFile(string originalFile, string patchedFile)
    {
        // Ensure target directory exists.
        var targetDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(patchedFile);
        if (targetDirectory == null) return;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDirectory);

        // Read file bytes.
        byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(originalFile);

        // Detect and patch file.
        for (int p = 0; p < fileContent.Length; p++)
        {
            if (!DetectPatch(fileContent, p)) continue;

            for (int w = 0; w < PatchFind.Length; w++)
            {
                fileContent[p + w] = PatchReplace[w];
            }
        }

        // Save it to another location.
        File.WriteAllBytes(patchedFile, fileContent);
    }
```

So how can i achieve the function to work with 2GB+ files. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which C# version are you *actually* working with? Those tags are about features specific to different versions. And I doubt you're compiling some code in each version :)

Comment: @Broots Waymb oh my bad. im using 4.x

Comment: Is the barrier that you're using `int` to index something that exceeds `int.MaxValue`? Loading such a file entirely into memory seems misguided to me.

Comment: `File.ReadAllBytes` is entirely misguided; use [`BinaryReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes for file larger than 2GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882004/system-io-file-readallbytes-for-file-larger-than-2gb)

Comment: @elgonzo nope its not the very same issue

Comment: Please explain how it is not the very same issue. Your issue is wanting to read and modify (patch) a file that is larger than 2GB. That is the problem you are trying to solve, correct? The question i referred to precisely addresses this problem.

Comment: @elgonzo but the problem is it only makes int value range higher it does not affect File.ReadAllBytes method

Comment: What? I do not understand your last comment...

Comment: @elgonzo what you told me to do only addresses another issue which is integer length. but my problem is not the integer length

Comment: No, the question i referred to is NOT about "integer length" (whatever you mean with that). It is about your problem. Anyway, you will have to read that question and its answer for yourself. I could regurgitate here word-for-word what is already written there in this question+answer; but then again, who would prefer reading my regurgitation instead of the actual text in the linked question+answer? ;-)

Comment: Don't try to read the entire file at once. Use Streams to only keep small chunks in memory at a time.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn its a very good idea too but it has its own disadvantages so i used another method. anyways thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `File.ReadAllBytes` will not open files with lengths longer than `Int.MaxValue`. Loading an entire file into memory just to scan it for a pattern is a bad design no matter how big the file is. You should open the file as a stream and use the Scanner pattern to step through the file, replacing bytes that match your pattern. A rather simplistic implementation  using `BinaryReader`:

```
static void PatchStream(Stream source, Stream target
    , IList<byte> searchPattern, IList<byte> replacementPattern)
{
    using (var input = new BinaryReader(source))
    using (var output = new BinaryWriter(target))
    {
        var buffer = new Queue<byte>();
        while (true)
        {
            if (buffer.Count < searchPattern.Count)
            {
                if (input.BaseStream.Position < input.BaseStream.Length)
                    buffer.Enqueue(input.ReadByte());
                else
                    break;
            }
            else if (buffer.Zip(searchPattern, (b, s) => b == s).All(c => c))
            {
                foreach (var b in replacementPattern)
                    output.Write(b);
                buffer.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                output.Write(buffer.Dequeue());
            }
        }

        foreach (var b in buffer)
            output.Write(b);
    }
}
```

You can call it on files with code like:

```
PatchStream(new FileInfo(...).OpenRead(),
    new FileInfo(...).OpenWrite(),
    new[] { (byte)'a', (byte)'b', (byte)'c' },
    new[] { (byte)'A', (byte)'B', (byte)'C' });
```

Comment: I did find the answer already and it is so similar to this so i consider this as the right answer !

Comment: @AquaDev: For your info: it is possible to answer your own question ;-)