# C# Byte[] Array offset searching in a 4gb file

Tags: c#, byte, offset

I have an application that have to replace certain byte arrays (all occurences) in a 4gb file (like HxD), and i would like help in that search of offsets, i need a function that search (fast) in the big file (4gb) and return the decimal offset of this byte array so i can replace it (i already have the replace method, i just need to get the decimal offset of each byte arrays). Thanks for reading this! PS: Sorry for my english.

Comment: Consult [How to read file over 2GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861230/).

Comment: @DourHighArch too long.... (120 seconds for one byte array searching)

Comment: Get it working before you start worrying about how long it takes. Why do you think 120 seconds is too long for a multi-GB file? If it really is, consider using `BinaryReader(BufferedStream(...))` but only after you have it working.

Comment: The problem is that the program is replacing byte array normally but i want to avoid updating the offset each time, i need to find a way to get the offset automatically.

Comment: 130 seconds is too long because the idea of the program is the speed, so if i can’t be faster tell me..

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at `MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile` Method - you can then create a `MemoryMappedViewStream`, and create a buffered stream to use to help find the array.  This post has some suggestions on doing the last part: [Best way to find position in the Stream where given byte sequence starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471975/best-way-to-find-position-in-the-stream-where-given-byte-sequence-starts).

Comment: What problems did you have trying to use MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile?