# The fastest method of searching a BINARY file(900mb - 4.5gb) for byte[] and grabbing the offset. C#

Tags: c#, offset, binaryfiles

basically **I want a faster and working method to search a binary file for a byte array and grabbing the offset**. The byte[] could contain between 5 - 50 bytes. It's gonna read 1 search
I have a function that's not working properly and very slow:

```
        static long ReadOneSrch(BinaryReader reader, byte[] bytes)
    {
        int b;
        long i = 0;
        while ((b = reader.BaseStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            if (b == bytes[i++])
            {
                if (i == bytes.Length)
                    return reader.BaseStream.Position - bytes.Length;
            }
            else
                i = b == bytes[0] ? 1 : 0;
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: You might have a look at the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) or its variants. It is most often formulated for text searches but also works for binary.

Comment: I've looked it up.... But I don't understand how can I use it in this situation, I would be thankful if you include some code.

Comment: Did you google for Boyer-Moore C#? I get several references here on Stack Overflow as well as github.

Comment: Yes, I just don't understand how can I use it in this context.

Comment: Will try to provide some code in a few hours

Comment: Do you understand how bower-moore works. The way you use it in this context is your lookup dictionary will have 256 entries, one for every possible value of a `byte`, instead of one entry for every possible value of a letter.

Comment: Unless the search pattern is very large, I doubt a better algorithm will help.  It's more efficient to read the whole file sequentially than to move the file pointer by small increments.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The pattern has about 30 items maximum

Comment: Get your code working before worrying whether it's the fastest. My answer to [How to read a file over 2GB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52883386/22437) shows how to scan large files for a pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my implementation using Boyer-Moore-Horspool on a stream.
The core BMH implementation is basically copied from [Boyer-Moore-Horspool Algorithm for All Matches (Find Byte array inside Byte array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252518/boyer-moore-horspool-algorithm-for-all-matches-find-byte-array-inside-byte-arra).

The method repeatedly reads the stream into a buffer and applies the BMH algorithm on the buffer until we get a match. In order to also find matches spanning two such reads, we always transfer the last pattern.Length bytes from the previous read to the head of the buffer (could be done even smarter with some effort by evaluating possibe match starts already excluded - but if the pattern is not too long you will hardly notice the difference).

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the first occurrence of <paramref name="pattern"/> in a stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">The input stream</param>
    /// <param name="pattern">The pattern</param>
    /// <returns>The index of the first occurrence, or -1 if the pattern has not been found</returns>
    public static long IndexOf(Stream s, byte[] pattern)
    {
        // Prepare the bad character array is done once in a separate step
        var badCharacters = MakeBadCharArray(pattern);

        // We now repeatedly read the stream into a buffer and apply the Boyer-Moore-Horspool algorithm on the buffer until we get a match
        var buffer = new byte[Math.Max(2 * pattern.Length, 4096)];
        long offset = 0; // keep track of the offset in the input stream
        while (true)
        {
            int dataLength;
            if (offset == 0)
            {
                // the first time we fill the whole buffer
                dataLength = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                // Later, copy the last pattern.Length bytes from the previous buffer to the start and fill up from the stream
                // This is important so we can also find matches which are partly in the old buffer
                Array.Copy(buffer, buffer.Length - pattern.Length, buffer, 0, pattern.Length);
                dataLength = s.Read(buffer, pattern.Length, buffer.Length - pattern.Length) + pattern.Length;
            }

            var index = IndexOf(buffer, dataLength, pattern, badCharacters);
            if (index >= 0)
                return offset + index; // found!
            if (dataLength < buffer.Length)
                break;
            offset += dataLength - pattern.Length;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    // --- Boyer-Moore-Horspool algorithm ---
    // (Slightly modified code from
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252518/boyer-moore-horspool-algorithm-for-all-matches-find-byte-array-inside-byte-arra)
    // Prepare the bad character array is done once in a separate step:
    private static int[] MakeBadCharArray(byte[] pattern)
    {
        var badCharacters = new int[256];

        for (long i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
            badCharacters[i] = pattern.Length;

        for (var i = 0; i < pattern.Length - 1; ++i)
            badCharacters[pattern[i]] = pattern.Length - 1 - i;

        return badCharacters;
    }

    // Core of the BMH algorithm
    private static int IndexOf(byte[] value, int valueLength, byte[] pattern, int[] badCharacters)
    {
        int index = 0;

        while (index <= valueLength - pattern.Length)
        {
            for (var i = pattern.Length - 1; value[index + i] == pattern[i]; --i)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    return index;
            }

            index += badCharacters[value[index + pattern.Length - 1]];
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: It's working perfectly! Though is there is a method of finding strings that aren't capitalized correctly. For example turning hello to bytes then searching the file. The file contains Hello but not hello. Is there a way to detect that too?

Comment: This is a rather different problem as you now want to search for text, not binary. Then immediately questions about text encoding, culture-dependencies and linguistic equivalence (the question whether of not two texts are equal is not solved by a simple byte-by-byte comparison, capitalization is culture-specific etc.) play a role.

Comment: That said: a very simple (and in general wrong!) approach would be to transform all bytes in the buffer corresponding to 'A'-'Z' to 'a'-'z' directly after the `s.Read`